# How to make Swingbench 2.6 and Oracle 18c work together?

Tags: oracle-18c

Swingbench 2.6 supports Oracle 12c and I have been using it for 12c successfully. But I want to use it with Oracle 18c for testing purposes.

In case of using different wizards from swingbench\winbin folder I was getting scripts hanging except oewizard script and could only run CRUD tests with it using SYSTEM user instead of SOE.

So how to fix Swingbench scripts and Oracle configuration for that?

Comment: Hi Gryu, I saw you removed your question from SQA.SE, I didnt know it was a stress testing tool, so maybe it is not off-topic. Still I expect (or hope) this community has more experience with this tool. Goodluck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Partially it could be fixed by adding

   alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;

command at the top of these five files:

```
swingbench/sql/CreUser.sql
swingbench/sql/json_createuser.sql
swingbench/sql/shdg_createuser.sql
swingbench/sql/soedgcreateuser.sql
swingbench/sql/tpcds_createuser.sql
```

2. During configuration `sys as sysdba` Administrator Username is filled by default. And during oewizard script execution Java throw a lot of

> `ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'`

exceptions. So I've resolved it by:

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL> grant unlimited tablespace to sys;
SQL> alter user sys quota unlimited on users;
```